# Need to send the checkbox Filtered Data from Child Component to Parent Component : React Hooks, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, state-management

I have a Parent Component (Product List.jsx) where I am displaying the Data coming from Store.
Now I have  Child Component (Side Nav.jsx) Where I have the Checkbox Filtered Data in "handleCheckChnage" function, Now I need to send the Filtered data to the Parent Component (Product List.jsx) and Display the Data Accordingly, Here I got Struck, Can anyone help in this, Thanks in Advance..

Here is the Parent Component (Product List.jsx)

```
const ProductList = () => {

      let dispatch = useDispatch();
      
      let getalldatafromserver = useSelector((state)=>{
              return state.FetchALLProducts;
      })

      useEffect(() => {
        
         dispatch(allActions.fetchallproducts());
        
      }, [])

   
        return (

            <React.Fragment>
              
                <div className="container">
                      <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-md-2">
                               <SideNav /> 
                          </div>
                          <div className="col-md-10">
                          <section className="mt-3">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col">
                                <p className="h3 text-success">Product List</p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex impedit, incidunt ipsum nulla sapiente sint suscipit? A animi, error et fuga ipsum minus, nam officia praesentium quisquam, recusandae soluta voluptate?</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            {
                               getalldatafromserver.products.length > 0 &&
                                getalldatafromserver.products.map(product => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="col-md-3" key={product.id}>
                                            <div className="card">
                                                <div className="card-header text-center bg-white">
                                                    <img src={product.image} alt="" width="150" height="150"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="card-body rgba-light-green-light">
                                                    <ul className="list-group">
                                                        <li className="list-group-item">
                                                            NAME : {product.name}
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li className="list-group-item">
                                                            PRICE : {product.price}
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li className="list-group-item">
                                                            QTY : {product.qty} Kgs
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col">
                                {
                                    // for empty data
                                    getalldatafromserver.products.length === 0 &&
                                    <p  className="font-weight-bold text-success text-center fw-bold">NO Records Found in Database</p>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                
            </React.Fragment>
```

Here is the Child Component (Side Nav.jsx)

```
const SideNav = () => {

    //Get data from Store
    const getDataFromStore = useSelector((state)=>{
          return state.FetchALLProducts;
    })
     
    //console.log(getDataFromStore.products);

   const [sidebar, setsidebar] = useState(false);

    const [checkUpdate, setcheckUpdate] = useState('')

   const [checkBoxes, setcheckBoxes] = useState([
    {name:"Orange",isChecked:false},
    {name:"Carrot",isChecked:false},
    {name:"Apple",isChecked:false},
    {name:"Potato",isChecked:false},
    {name:"Avacados",isChecked:false}
])

   const showSidebar =() =>{
        setsidebar(true);
   }

    const handleCheckChnage =(e) =>{
        //console.log(e.target.value);
        var allcheckboxes = [...checkBoxes];
        //console.log(allcheckboxes);
            allcheckboxes.forEach((cbox)=>{
                  if(cbox.name === e.target.value){
                      if(cbox.isChecked){
                          cbox.isChecked =false
                      }else{
                          cbox.isChecked = true
                      }
                  }
            })
              setcheckBoxes(allcheckboxes);

              let defaultData = [...getDataFromStore.products];

                 const filter = defaultData.filter((newData)=>{
                          //console.log(newData);
                          if(e.target.value === newData.name){
                             // console.log(newData);
                             if(e.target.checked){
                                console.log(newData);
                                setcheckUpdate(newData);
                               
                             }else if(!e.target.checked){
                                console.log(defaultData);
                             }
                          }
                 })
              
    }

    const selectAll =(e) =>{
        //console.log(e.target.checked);
        let newcheckboxes = [...checkBoxes];
        if(e.target.checked){
            newcheckboxes.forEach((allbox)=>{
                  allbox.isChecked = true;
            })
        }else{
            newcheckboxes.forEach((allbox)=>{
                allbox.isChecked = false;
          })
        }
        setcheckBoxes(newcheckboxes);
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
         <i className="fas fa-align-justify yes" onClick={showSidebar} ></i>
            {
                sidebar &&
                <div className="form-group mt-3">
                <label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Choose Health</label> <br/>
                <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="all" onChange={(e)=>{selectAll(e)}} />
                <span style={{marginLeft:'5px',fontWeight:"bold"}}>All Skils</span>
                 {
                      checkBoxes.map((cb)=>
                      <div className="form-check">
                     <label className="form-check-label" >{cb.name}</label>
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking" value={cb.name} checked={cb.isChecked} onChange={(e)=>{handleCheckChnage(e)}} />
                  </div>
                  ) 
                 }
                </div>
            }
   
    
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default SideNav;
```

Here is the Reducer

```
let initialstate ={
    loading : false,
    products :[],
    singleproduct :{},
    error : ''

}

 export const reducer = (state =initialstate , action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case bigActions.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS :
            return {
                ...state,
                products : action.payload
            }
           
            case bigActions.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST : 
            return {
                  ...state,
                  loading : true
            }

            case bigActions.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS : 
            return {
                  ...state,
                  loading : false
            }

            case bigActions.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE : 
            return {
                  ...state,
                  loading : false
            }
            
            case bigActions.DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST :
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading : true
                }
                case bigActions.DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS :
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading : false
                }

                case bigActions.DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE :
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading : false
                }

                case bigActions.GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_REQUEST :
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading : true
                    }
                 
                    case bigActions.GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS :
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading : false,
                        singleproduct : action.payload
                    }

                    case bigActions.GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_FAILURE :
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        loading : false
                    }
                   
                    case bigActions.UPDATE_PRODUCT_FORM :
                        return {
                            ...state,
                            singleproduct: {
                                ...state.singleproduct,
                                [action.payload.key] : action.payload.value
                            }
                        }

                        case bigActions.UPDATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
                            return {
                                   ...state,
                              loading : false
                                     };
            default: return state
    }
}
```

Here is the Actions

```
import axios from "axios";

export const GET_ALL_PRODUCTS ="GET_ALL_PRODUCTS";
export const UPDATE_PRODUCT_FORM ="UPDATE_PRODUCT_FORM";

export const CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST ="CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST";
export const CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS ="CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS";
export const CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE ="CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE";

export const DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST ="DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST";
export const DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS ="DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS";
export const DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE ="DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE";

export const GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_REQUEST ="GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_REQUEST";
export const GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS ="GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS";
export const GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_FAILURE ="GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_FAILURE";

export const UPDATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS ="UPDATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS";

export const fetchallproducts=()=>{
      return async (dispatch)=>{
           try {
          
              let dataUrl ="http://localhost:3000/users";
              let response = await axios.get(dataUrl);
              dispatch({type:GET_ALL_PRODUCTS, payload:response.data});

           } catch(error){
              console.log(error)
           }
      }
}

//Create a Product

export const createproduct =(product,history) =>{
   return async (dispatch)=>{
         try {
             dispatch({type:CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST});
             let dataUrl ="http://localhost:3000/users";
             let response = await axios.post(dataUrl,product);
             dispatch({type:CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,payload:response.data});
             history.push('/admindeatils');
         }catch(error){
            dispatch({type:CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,payload:error});
         }
   }
}

// Delete a Product
export const deleteproduct =(productId)=>{
   return async (dispatch) =>{
      try {
         dispatch({type:DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST})
         let dataUrl =`http://localhost:3000/users/${productId.id}`;
         let res = await axios.delete(dataUrl);
         dispatch({type:DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,payload:res.data});
         dispatch(fetchallproducts());
      } catch (error){
          dispatch({type:DELETE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,payload:error})
      }
 
   }
}

// Get a Single Product

export const singleProduct =(id) =>{

   return {
      type:GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
      payload : id,
      
   }
      // return async (dispatch) =>{
      //     try{
      //          dispatch({type:GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_REQUEST});
      //          let dataURL = `http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`;
      //          let response = await axios.get(dataURL);
      //          dispatch({type:GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,payload:response.data})
      //     } catch (error){
      //           dispatch({type:GET_SINGLE_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,payload:error})
      //     }
      // }
}

export const updateProductForm = (key, value) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
       dispatch({
           type: UPDATE_PRODUCT_FORM,
           payload : {key,value}
       });
   };
};

export const updateProduct = (product, productId , history) => {
   return async (dispatch) => {
       try {
           let dataURL = `http://localhost:3000/users/${productId}`;
           let response = await axios.put(dataURL,product);
           dispatch({type : UPDATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS , payload : response.data});
           // redirect to Admin Page
           history.push('/admindeatils')
       }
       catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
       }
   };
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are keeping the updated data based on the checkbox in your component and not in the redux store?

Comment: No I am actually New this React and Redux, So I Just  Kept that in Component , SO Can You tell me How can I send that Updated data to Parent Component ?

Comment: You can keep all your data in the redux and get it from there. 

The current code doesn't show the entire code structure. If you can update the code with reducer and action then that'll be helpful.

Comment: @Mehul Thakkar , I just updated the Reducer and Actions , CAn you please look in to that and give an Solution?

Comment: I have added to the chatroom if you can join I can try to help there.

Comment: I cant see any Chat Room Here, Please can you tell me how to join?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237659/discussion-between-sundeep-and-mehul-thakkar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the entire data from the redux store for checkboxes.

**Reducer**

```js
let initialstate ={
    loading : false,
    products :[],
    singleproduct :{},
    error : '',
    checkBoxes: [
    {name:"Orange",isChecked:false},
    {name:"Carrot",isChecked:false},
    {name:"Apple",isChecked:false},
    {name:"Potato",isChecked:false},
    {name:"Avacados",isChecked:false}
    ]

}

 export const reducer = (state =initialstate , action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
       // Earlier cases.
        case bigActions.UPDATE_CHECKBOXES:
            return {
                ...state,
                checkBoxes : action.payload
            }
           
            
       default: return state
    }
}
```

**Action**

```js
import axios from "axios";


// Existing code...
export const UPDATE_CHECKBOXES ="UPDATE_CHECKBOXES";


// Existing code...
export const updateCheckBoxes = (checkBoxes) => { // checkboxes should contain the updated checkboxes from handleChange.
   return (dispatch) => {
       dispatch({
           type: UPDATE_CHECKBOXES,
           payload : checkBoxes
       });
   };
};
```

**Sidenav Component**

```js
const SideNav = () => {

    let dispatch = useDispatch();


    //Get data from Store
    const getDataFromStore = useSelector((state)=>{
          return state.FetchALLProducts;
    })
     
    //console.log(getDataFromStore.products);

   const [sidebar, setsidebar] = useState(false);

    const [checkUpdate, setcheckUpdate] = useState('')

   const {checkBoxes} = getDataFromStore

   const showSidebar =() =>{
        setsidebar(true);
   }

    const handleCheckChnage =(e) =>{
        //console.log(e.target.value);
        var allcheckboxes = [...checkBoxes];
        //console.log(allcheckboxes);
            allcheckboxes.forEach((cbox)=>{
                  if(cbox.name === e.target.value){
                      if(cbox.isChecked){
                          cbox.isChecked =false
                      }else{
                          cbox.isChecked = true
                      }
                  }
            })
              dispatch(allActions.updateCheckBoxes(allcheckboxes));

              let defaultData = [...getDataFromStore.products];

                 const filter = defaultData.filter((newData)=>{
                          //console.log(newData);
                          if(e.target.value === newData.name){
                             // console.log(newData);
                             if(e.target.checked){
                                console.log(newData);
                                setcheckUpdate(newData);
                               
                             }else if(!e.target.checked){
                                console.log(defaultData);
                             }
                          }
                 })
              
    }

    const selectAll =(e) =>{
        //console.log(e.target.checked);
        let newcheckboxes = [...checkBoxes];
        if(e.target.checked){
            newcheckboxes.forEach((allbox)=>{
                  allbox.isChecked = true;
            })
        }else{
            newcheckboxes.forEach((allbox)=>{
                allbox.isChecked = false;
          })
        }
        dispatch(allActions.updateCheckBoxes(newcheckboxes));
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
         <i className="fas fa-align-justify yes" onClick={showSidebar} ></i>
            {
                sidebar &&
                <div className="form-group mt-3">
                <label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Choose Health</label> <br/>
                <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="all" onChange={(e)=>{selectAll(e)}} />
                <span style={{marginLeft:'5px',fontWeight:"bold"}}>All Skils</span>
                 {
                      checkBoxes.map((cb)=>
                      <div className="form-check">
                     <label className="form-check-label" >{cb.name}</label>
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking" value={cb.name} checked={cb.isChecked} onChange={(e)=>{handleCheckChnage(e)}} />
                  </div>
                  ) 
                 }
                </div>
            }
   
    
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default SideNav;
```

**ProductList**

```js
const ProductList = () => {

      let dispatch = useDispatch();
      
      let getalldatafromserver = useSelector((state)=>{
              return state.FetchALLProducts;
      })
      
      const {checkBoxes} = getalldatafromserver; // You'll get the checkboxes data here

   
        return (<DOM></DOM>)
        }
```